# How can i get the status of a column using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I mean, is there any way to know if a column is hidden? i just learned to hide them with

```
$('#tableG td:nth-child('+(index+1)+'), #tableG th:nth-child('+(index+1)+')').hide();
```

but now i need to get the status, is there anything like:

```
if($('#tableG th:nth-child('+(index+1)+')').show() == true) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use this kind of notation:

```
$(element).is(":visible")
```

so:

```
if($('#tableG th:nth-child('+(index+1)+')').is(":visible")) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the [jQuery :visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)